# change variable in Pycharm debugger

Tags: python, pycharm

When I debug my Python code in Pycharm I often want to change some of the variables that are being set by the original code.
I can do this via the Debugger tab, click on the respective variable and use the Set Value function to change it. This feels too much clicking around and I would prefer to do it via the console interface. But when I try this, it doesn't update the variable:

```
>>> filename
Out[6]: 'a'
>>> filename='b'
>>> filename
Out[8]: 'a'
```

Is there a way to change these type of variables via the console interface?

Comment: try to go through the scope, e.g. `locals()["filename"] = "b"` or `globals()["filename"] = "b"` (depending on what kind of variable it is), or `setattribute(yourmodue, "filename", "b")`.

Comment: @qarma The filename variable is indeed present in `locals()`, but `locals()["filename"]="b"` does have no effect.

Comment: How about `locals().update(filename="b")`?

Comment: @qarma Unfortunately `locals().update(filename='b')` doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Use the magic button]

You can totally do that. When stopped at a breakpoint:

1. In the debugger console tab, click on **A** "*Show Python Prompt*"
2. Type your python code at **B** to modify the variables at the prompt that shows up
3. See the results in the console pane at **C**

Note: The interactive console echoed commands (lines with >>> by C in the image) disappear if you toggle the button off and when the program ends which is kinda weird. I often want to copy the commands I entered.

Comment: @Jan-Willem how about marking this answer as correct?

Comment: 1. It doesn't answer OP question. OP knows how to open debugger and 2. This will make a copy of object. If you will run your program you see unchanged values. Checked PyCharm Pro 2019.2

Answer (score 7):

It seems like a bug, the answer above shows that it is possible to manipulate the state of already existing objects, however it seems to be impossible to assign new values (or objects) to the variable itself.

See the following snippet for clarification:

```
>>> var_obj.temp = 1
>>> var_obj
Out[2]: namespace(temp=1)
>>> var_obj.temp2 = 2
>>> var_obj.temp = 10
>>> var_obj
Out[5]: namespace(temp=10, temp2=2)
>>> var_simple = 10
>>> var_simple
Out[7]: 1
```

The issue was already reported to the PyCharm issue tracker back in 2013 ([see the link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11224)).
People report that the issue is present since PyCharm 3, some have suggested that it might be a python issue and not PyCharm but its not clear why.

Anyway, the behavior is confusing and should at least be taken into account when trying to debug - until it is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't do this via the console that you can pop up in the debug session. You can only change things via the debug tab, right clicking and then changing it. Unfortunate, but thats how it is.

Comment: This worked for me. From the "Debugger" tab, in the "Variables" sub-window, I right-clicked the variable and was able to select the "Set Value..." option. The default keybinding will allow me to simply select the variable and click F2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons that escape me the obvious "Change Value/F2) lets you insert a value but will not persist it to the underlying variable/attribute on

But ... you can open the "Evaluate Expression (Alt-f8) window while highlighting the variable or attribute, then assign a new value to it in the window