# debug python code and change variables at runtime in pyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

I am using pycharm to 2018.3.4 to develop python scripts and I am still pretty new in this language, I normally write PowerShell code. I have a question concerning debugging. Take this unfinished code as an example.

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the clipboard.
import pyperclip, re, sys

phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    (\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+)\)?([ .-–\/]?)([\d]+))
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

mailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
    \w+@\w+\.\w+
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

text = pyperclip.paste()

def getMatches(text, regex) :
    return regex.findall(text)

Emails = getMatches(text,mailRegex) #I want to play with this variable at runtime
phone  = getMatches(text,phoneRegex)
```

I am at the stage where I want to analyze the variable Emails at runtime. So I set a breakpoint and can view the contents of the varieble just fine. However I also want to run some methods and play with their input parameters at runtime. Does someone know how this is possible? If this is possible with another IDE then this would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm 2018.3.4 you simply do this by clicking on the **console tab** and then on the **show command prompt** button.

[image: changing variables at runtime in PyCharm]

Now you can type in **Emails** or **Emails.pop()** for example in order to manipulate variables:

[image: python command prompt]

You can also refer to this post, where this was discussed for an older version: [change variable in Pycharm debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695187/change-variable-in-pycharm-debugger)